# Question about continuous functions on two metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

Given two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$ and given that $f$and $g$ are continuous mappings from $X \to Y$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x\in A$ where $A$ is a subset of $X$. Prove that $f(x)=g(x)$ holds true for every $x\in \bar{A}$

What I thought is that if $x\in \bar{A}$ then x is either in A or A'. So the case for A is very easy But I can't think about something for A'

Comment: In that case, there is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ that converges to $x$.

Comment: I want a way which I can picturize or draw a picture about that method @DavidMitra

Comment: Recall one definition of continuity in metric spaces which says: "f is continuous at $x$ if $(x_n)$ converging to $x$ implies that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. What is the characterisation of the closure of A?

Comment: What do you mean by characterization  of closure of A @JackDavies

Comment: @Rememberme Properties of $\overline A$ that determine it (is what Jack Davies meant).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose by contradiction there is a $x\in A'$ with $f(x)\neq g(x)$. As $Y$ is metric and so Hausdorff we have disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ with $f(x)\in U$ and $g(x)\in V$. As $f$ and $g$ are continuous $f^{-1}(U)$ and $g^{-1}(V)$ are open sets in $X$ and so is their intersection. Notice $x\in f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(V)$, and as $x$ is a limit point of $A$ there must be some $y\in A$ such that $y\in f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(V)$. The image of $y$ through $f$ is an element of $U$, and the image of $y$ through $g$ is an element of $V$, as these sets are disjoint we must have $f(y)\neq g(y)$ which contradicts our hypothesis as $y\in A$.